# Summer and wintertime JAVA

Tags: java

i have this code:

```
    Locale locale1 = Locale.GERMANY;
    TimeZone tz1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin");
    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(tz1,locale1);
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
```

When the time switch from winter to summer my time is not correct anymore. Is there any workaround or solution this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What _is_ the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "not correct anymore"? What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this inDaylightTime : [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#observesDaylightTime()) to check whether you are in daylight saving. For example :

```
if (tz1.inDaylightTime) cal.add(Calendar.HOUR,1);
```

Comment: Is the code OK now ?

Comment: Thanks, that makes it all clear.

Comment: I will try this i hope it works on the switch day:D